# how to set a tab bar disabled when loading its viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I had a problem with uitabbar. I want to make it disabled when that page is loaded. how to do that. can any one help me. i am using tabbar and adding it as sub view of toolbar

Comment: What is "loading" on the page? Are you waiting for a urlrequest?Tthere is always the userInteratctionEnabled: method.

Comment: you only want to disable the tabBar or complete view..

Comment: i want to disable only a single tab in tabbar not the entire tabbar...

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in two ways:

1. You can set its parameter "User Interction Enabled" unchcked in the Interface Bulder, if you are using it ths way
2. You can set it programatically:

> ```
> -(void) loadView {
>     [super loadView];
>     tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
>  }
> ```

and after then set:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

You have to set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES on the controller you are going to push into the view...
You have to do this before pushing it in the navigationcontroller and after initialization line.